# Sphinx not documenting functions with decorators

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators

### Issue:

I currently am trying to document a library I created. Some of the functions in the class use decorators. The thing is, the decorators return a class instance and not the function itself. Sphinx doesn't like this, and won't document the function unless the decorator is gone. All other functions without this decorator document fine, so I know it's not me. Let me show you an example of this:

#### Example:

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

class Command(Generic[Callable[P, T]]):
    def __init__(self, function: Callable[P, T], **kwargs) -> None:
        self.function = function
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return self.function(**self.kwargs)


def to_command(**kwargs):
    def wrapped(func: Callable) -> Command:
        new = Command(**kwargs)
        return new

    return wrapped
    

# In the class that sphinx should be documenting:
@to_command(name='foo', description='bar')
async def foo_bar(self, *, name: str, description: str) -> None:
    """This is a doc string that isnt showing up"""
    pass
```

Please note this example is a VERY stripped example to show intent, it is not actually the code that's being used.

### So the question:

Would it be best to create a custom sphinx ext to parse these instances? How would I even do that? Is there an easy way to get around this so sphinx documents the functions? Any information or links to documentation that could help me would be amazing.

Comment: I would suggest that you search the [Sphinx issue tracker for "decorator"](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues?q=decorator).

Comment: Also search here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-sphinx%5D+decorator